# Primefaces datatable: Unable to retrieve selected rows and selection get lost with pagination

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, pagination

I am using primefaces datatable for checkbox based selection and try to implement [given example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf). They used Model say, **userModel** which could implement SelectableDataModel interface. I don't want to use model so I used **rowKey** for this purpose.

E.g

datatable.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="item" value="#{userBean.allItems}"
       paginatorPosition="bottom" paginator="true" rows="3"
       selection="#{userBean.selectedItems}" rowKey="#{item[0]}">

       <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

       <p:columns value="#{userBean.itemColHeader}" columnIndexVar="colIndex" var="colName" >
       <f:facet name="header" >
           <h:outputText value="#{colName}"/>
       </f:facet>
           <h:outputText value="#{item[colIndex]}"/>
       </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here,

`allItems = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

`selectedItems = ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

`selectedItems = ArrayList<String>`

userBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@ViewScoped
public class userBean implements SelectableDataModel {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectedItems;

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getSelectedItems() {
        return selectedItems;
    }

    public void setSelectedItems(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> selectedUsers) {
        this.selectedItems = selectedItems;
    }
}
```

My problem:

```
1) When I select mulitple rows, selectedUsers remains empty.
2) After selecting next page, previous selection get lost.
```

I went through @BelusC [blog](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/using-datatables.html) and found that binding is possible solution but unable to solve my problem with his instructions. Is converter needed..? Is there any thing wrong with my approach. Thanks

**Update:1**

The reason behind using Arraylist of Arraylist(**allItems**) is only to make datatable generic. I need not to bother about the no of columns while drawing datatables. That is why I want to retrieve the selected items which should not depend on object([like](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf): car[ ] selectedcars)

Comment: It's been past 4 years and you even selected an answer?
If you solved the problem post the answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issues and I solved it using `<p:ajax>`.

First I would do as akoskm says and have a unique row key.

Then I would use an array (`List<String>[]`) (`List` is more generic than `ArrayList`) for `selectedItems`

And finally you can add:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" process="@this"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" process="@this"/>
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Just make sure you have an `<h:form>` around the table

That will make sure that the component pushes the data to the bean. I'm not sure if it will solve the pagination problem though, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

`rowKey="#{item[0]}"` makes no sense to me. it will point to the same (0) object in every iteration. While in the dataTable demo it points to the current `car.model`.

Have you tried to change to #{item}?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. I used it but still not solved. If I used rowkey = #{item} it means table records(rows) become a key, then what will be the datatype for selectedItems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer : [Primefaces datatable with checkbox selection ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128945/primefaces-datatable-with-checkbox-selection-only)

You can solve this problem using `rowSelectionMode="add"`