# Primefaces datatable with checkbox selection ONLY

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my project, I use datatable with `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />` 
so that the entries can be multiple selected using the checkboxes.

However, when the user click on a row, all previous selection is unselected and only that row is selected.
This behaviour is unexpected and annoying.
I would like to disable the behaviour of rowSelect and rowUnselect on row clicking, but seems I had no way to do but hacking the source of datatable.js.

Does anyone implement this before? Thanks for answering.

Using:

primefaces 3.5

mojarra 2.1.6

glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: Provide your code. So that we can find the error or logical mistake in that.

Comment: Here his code is not important as the same issue is happening in the [showcase itself](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf). It seems to be only with the checkbox and not with radio button. I also want to get the same behaviour the OP mentioned. Anybody has solved that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7103), this feature is now supported in Primefaces versions **5.0.3** & **5.1** by simply adding rowSelectMode="checkbox" to the datatable.

Documentation reference (PF 5.1):

> Use rowSelectMode option to customize the default behavior on row
>   click of a multiple selection enabled datatable. Default value is
>   "new" that clears previous selections, "add" mode keeps previous
>   selections same as selecting a row with mouse click when metakey is on
>   and "checkbox" mode allows row selection with checkboxes only.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your page, might help stopping selection when you click a row.

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("tr td").click(function(event) {
            if (!$(this).find("div").hasClass("ui-chkbox") 
                  || $(this).find("div").find("div").hasClass("ui-state-disabled")
                  || this == event.target) {
                event.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

The last condition (`this == event.target`) is needed when clicking the checkbox column itself outside of the checkbox.

Comment: Rather than mark this down, I should point out that the code above still effects the same issue, but localises it to one cell.