# PrimeFaces 3.5 and DataTables (multiple selection)

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

I am currently experiencing a lot of troubles with the new release of PrimeFaces (3.5). Here's an example piece of code:

```
<p:dataTable var="obj" id="objDataTable"
value="#{backingBean.objects}" rowKey="#{obj.id}"
paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
paginatorPosition="top" rows="15" editable="true"
selection="#{backingBean.selectedObjects}">

<p:column styleClass="headcol" selectionMode="multiple" />

    <p:column headerText="name" sortBy="#{obj.name}"
    filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{obj.name}"
    styleClass="headcol">
    <h:outputText value="#{obj.name}" />
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

When I click the checkboxes in the rows, I can select multiple rows, not a problem there. But once you click an actual row, you lose the selection. I am experiencing more problems than this one alone, but would like to start with this problem. I am going to post the same question on the PrimeFaces forum. This could also be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128945/primefaces-datatable-with-checkbox-selection-only), but there was literally no documentation on that question so I rather ask it again.

Comment: To clarify a bit further: with PrimeFaces 3.4.1, when I do not provide a selectionMode on the DataTable in combination with the checkboxes to select rows, I was unable to select a row by clicking on it. (also the ui-state-hover class was not used) . Since 3.5, the behaviour of the table has completely changed, and I am unable to find any notes about this in the documentation.

Comment: This is exactly how showcase works http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf using checkboxes and this seems logical to me

Comment: I have seen that the showcase has been showing this behaviour as well. It seems logic to me too, only that now our clients will need to press 'ctrl' when selecting multiple rows, whereas before that was not the case. I can smell bug-reports coming in ! I would like to know if there is an option to return to the previous behaviour, and if so, how to accomplish that.

Comment: Agreed on the lack of documentation. It's awful. I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and have run into this exact same issue. It's obviously an unintuitive pattern, but it appears to be  the default behaviour. I wanted to try and stop the <td> event from triggering (stopPropagtion), but doing so "disables" the checkbox. I also thought about doing the same thing, but reattaching the styling classes to the checkboxes, but obviously, Primefaces must trigger some kind of sequestered method to serialise and XHR post the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since nothing came up here I'd just like to add what I was told on the PrimeFaces-forum, (which confirms Serkan's comment on the original post) , this is -despite being new- desired behaviour, and for that reason not a bug. Some additional JQuery would (and in my case probably is going to) be able to work around this feature.

Answer (score 1):

add option `rowSelectMode="add"` in your `<p:dataTable>`